# What to use as a string delimiter?

Tags: html, regex, drop-down-menu

I am going to put some sort of delimiter to define a boundary between field labels, field data, and separate fields *in the text of options for a dropdown*. This will be used to parse the text for a side visual. The user will be able to see the delimiter.

### What should I use as a delimiter that the user wont notice but will still be easily distinguishable in a regex?

I was thinking of using square brackets (there will be no brackets in the data, and other delimiters can be screened as well).

```
[ --select some option-- ]
 | [name] Travis [number] 9801 [root] 99 |
```

Comment: Have you considered using data attributes instead? It would be a lot less trouble and the user will never know unless he views the page source.

Comment: @Chuck - Please add this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is just to associate data with the element for handling on the client side, a better approach would probably be to store this info in data attributes. For example:

```
<select>
    <option value="1" data-name="Travis" data-number="9801" data-root="99">Travis</option>
</select>
```

Then JavaScript can use the data attributes (with jQuery it's `yourOption.data('root')`, and with plain JavaScript you can use it like a normal attribute) and the user won't even know it's there unless he looks at your source.

Answer (score 2):

Consider putting data into value of the OPTION element... You can even use JSON there like:

```
<option value="{name:Travis, number:9801, root:99}">Travis 9801</option>
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but overwriting the `value` with something like a JSON object here will remove the functionality of using `value` as an indexer with an id attached to it for posting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if square brackets are a good choice for a delimeter, mainly because you would only use the left or right bracket and the text would look incomplete (e.g. `Value1 ] Value2 ] Value 3`).

Personally, I prefer using pipes (`|`) for delimeters because it's not a commonly used character.

Comment: I like pipes as well, as long as they all line up right. They tend to look very unorganized when there are pipes which are scattered in my opinion. I was implying for the square brackets a surrounding, not necessarily single use as shown in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Do not store your data in the GUI strings.  If your boss asks you to stop showing the "root" in the drop-down options, it would be silly to tell him that you have to rewrite your data model.  Data doesn't like to live in strings -- they are opaque, slow, impossible to make type safe, and leave you vulnerable to injection attacks.

You're program needs to know about a guy named Travis with number 9801 and root 99, so keep that data around programmatically and generate your options strings from it (formatted however you like).

Comment: The strings are dynamically created in a generic factory based on the db model. A single change to the db model will result in a different string being produced. My users actually need to see the field names because there will be sometimes four different numeric fields. For example, if Travis 56 2893 57 109 was displayed, it would be hard to decipher without knowledge of each field and their order.

Comment: Why do these strings need to be regex friendly?  I assumed that you were trying to parse information out of the strings.

Comment: I am making a dashboard to facilitate the selection of the dropdown. Its contents and filtering will be generated based on the options.